# How to handle exception in empty return data with IEnumerable<decimal> C#

Tags: c#, dapper

I am using Dapper and want to return Today's Sales amount using a Stored Procedure but if there is no sale for today, it returns empty values which in turn throws an exception "'Object reference not set to an instance of an object." at the line with the `Query`.

How to handle that exception?

**Code Used**

```cs
public decimal GetAllSaleTotal(string connectionStringName = "POS")
{
    string connectionString = GetConnectionString(connectionStringName);
    using (IDbConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        var result = connection.Query<decimal>("dbo.GetTotalSales", commandType: 
                    CommandType.StoredProcedure).First();
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: where do you get the error? if on `.First()` you could try replace it with `FirstOrDefault()` and handle null value in code

Comment: I am getting the error on Line: 6 which is ```var result = xxxx```
I tried ```.Single()```, .```FirstOrDefault()``` but still the same error. @timur

Comment: Try `decimal?` (either by itself, or with `FirstOrDefault()`). You'd need to decide what to do in the case that the result is `null` though. I've not used Dapper though, so this might not work - it's just my guess.

Comment: I think @John is onto something - `Query<T>` returns `IEnumerable<T>` and `decimal` is a value type

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you handle the exception using try..catch statement.

Also, you should use
`var result = connection.Query<decimal?>("dbo.GetTotalSales", commandType:  CommandType.StoredProcedure).FirstOrDefault();`

Comment: You shouldn't choose exception handling when a better alternative exists.

Comment: Thanks @Ramesh Shah. This worked like a charm. Thank a lot for resolving this. I never wanted to use a try catch block. I was just wondering if I could use some null checks.

Comment: @NilanjanRoy you can mark it as an answer. If it's correct or upvote it.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I might handle it. Use `Take` to get 0 or 1 rows, then check the length.

```
public decimal GetAllSaleTotal(string connectionStringName = "POS")
{
    string connectionString = GetConnectionString(connectionStringName);
    using (IDbConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        var result = connection.Query<decimal>
        (
            commandText: "dbo.GetTotalSales", 
            commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure
        ).Take(1).ToList();
        return result.Count > 0 ? result[0] : 0M;
    }
}
```